# Time and memory limits as parameters in Metric-FF

Tags: c, bash, artificial-intelligence, planning, pddl

When running Metric-FF, it does not appear any time or memory limitations as possible input parameters. My question is, is it possible to introduce them as input parameters when running the planner?
The cited planner is the following one:
https://fai.cs.uni-saarland.de/hoffmann/metric-ff.html

Comment: I suspect, given a total absence of activity for 5 hours, that you've not managed to contact the correct audience for this question.  I've no idea what Metric-FF is, so I'm not qualified to answer — but maybe if you gave a URL to it, maybe help might be possible.  Or maybe not.  I suggest trying some sort of change — perhaps there are better tags (planning and pddl have very low memberships), or perhaps you need to reword something (title, question — which is admirably succinct, but maybe too succinct).

Comment: How much time and memory metric-ff consumes is discussed in papers like [Attack Planning in the Real World](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.4044.pdf). On page 6 there is a comparison between SGPlan and Metric-FF which prooves that Metric-FF uses significant more memory than any other planner.